# Jsoup How do I parse this span for its text?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<span class="c-city__hrMin" data-bind="{attr:{id:'p'+id()}}" id="p64">10:52</span>
```

How do I get this to print out just 10:52

So far I have tried

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String [] args) {
Document doc = null;

try {


    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/personal.html").get();
    String title = doc.title();
    Elements elements = doc.select(".c-city__hrMin");
    System.out.println("Website : " + title + elements.text());

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
}
```

From this the output is Website : The Personal World Clock but their isn't any syntax error

Comment: What is the output you get? Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Simply

`doc.select(".c-city__hrMin")` should work.

But if this class `c-city__hrMin` presents in other elements too then try

`doc.select(span[class=c-city__hrMin])` It will select all *span* element having that class exclusively.

**NB:** For more reference and idea about **Jsoup CSS Selectors** follow [this](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). You can try the selectors for a documents [here](https://try.jsoup.org/) also.